# Tkinter Binding "<Control-Key-n>" vs. "<Control-n>"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

I have a question:

When binding a function in tkinter, there are many ways to do it. Two of the ways are:

```
# Method 1
root.bind('<Control-n>', ExampleFunction)

# Method 2
root.bind('<Control-Key-n>', ExampleFunction)
```

What would be the difference between Control-n and Control-Key-n?

Comment: Nothing, just more than one way to reference to it. `'<Key-Up>'` same as `'<Up>'`.

Comment: You do sometimes have to use the longer form to avoid ambiguities.  For example, a digit in the range 1..5 would be interpreted as a button number by default, you have to put `Key-` in front of it to make it a keyboard event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally, there is no difference.

`Control-Key-n` is an event specifier consisting of

1. The modifier `Control` (the control key was held down when the event occurred.)
2. The event type `Key` (short for `KeyPress`)
3. The event detail `n` (specifically, the `n` key was pressed).

From `man n bind`:

> If a keysym *detail* is  given,  then
> the *type* field may be omitted;  it will default to **KeyPress**.  For example, **<Control-comma>** is equivalent to **<Control-KeyPress-comma>**.

So `<Control-n>` is just an abbreviated form of `<Control-Key-n>` (which itself is an abbreviated form of `<Control-KeyPress-n>`): `n` alone is equivalent to `Key-n`.